# Lenovo volume and brightness keys not working on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: sound, shortcut-keys, lenovo, brightness, volume-control

They worked fine in Ubuntu 17.04 and 17.10, but nothing happens in Ubuntu 18.04.

Running `xev` I can see the key presses are being interpreted correctly. I see `XF86AudioMute`, `XF86AudioRaiseVolume`, `XF86AudioLowerVolume`, `XF86MonBrightnessDown`, and `XF86MonBrightnessUp` key press and key release events. But the volume doesn't go up or down. The screen doesn't change brightness.

Possibly related, the button which switches on and off the trackpad *does* work, but the on-screen indicator which used to accompany it has stopped showing. (Which looked similar to the on-screen indicators for volume and brightness under previous versions of Ubuntu.)

The volume up, down, and mute keybindings in `gnome-control-center` are correct.

Lenovo ideapad 510S.

**Update:** I was using a Cairo Dock session. Things work fine in a GNOME on Xorg session.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem on 18.04 (went straight there from 16.04), and I think it's due to Cairo Dock not playing well with Gnome settings daemon. See [gnome-settings-daemon grabs multimedia keys and drops mute since upgrade 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/848856/gnome-settings-daemon-grabs-multimedia-keys-and-drops-mute-since-upgrade-16-04).

Possibly more, relevant, details in this [bug report.](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1248368)

Using the (g)settings keyboard to bind an appropriate command doesn't appear to work either, so I've only managed a workaround solution by enabling the compiz 'Commands' plugin (using the CompizConfig Settings Manager), grabbing the same keys (XF86AudioRaiseVolume, LowerVolume, etc.), and assigning appropriate commands, e.g. to increase audio volume

```
/usr/bin/pactl -- set-sink-volume 0 +5%
```

(there's no visual feedback like with Gnome-shell, but the volume is changed)